# Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate the value of..no single-int-arg constructor/factory method

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

i m havving register class like this

```
 package com.xyz.model;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize; 
    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)


    public class Register {
        private String Name;
        private String Email;
        private String Password;


        // getter and setter

        public Register()
        {}
    }
```

and this is my service code

```
public String Register(Register reg) {

        String url ="someurl" ;

        String name = reg.getName();
        //same for email and password
        JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
        jsondata.put("Name", name);
    //same for email password

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new Connection().getConnection(jsondata
                .toString());
//......code for connection to url..


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("failed"+e.getMessage());

        }
```

every time its going in catch block and  showing  error with message

```
failed Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.xyz.model.Register] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.xyz.model.Register] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method.
```

any help where i am doing wrong.